# How do you apply smooth modifier to a certain area while changing its texture material?

Tags: texturing, uv, edit-mode

[image]

Hello, so i've build this Astronaut and began to UV color its body. At the Helmet it gets complicated.. I wanted to make it smooth and glassy, made another Material by roughness 0 and adding a bit transmission, selected the area I wanted to change and assigned the area. Low and behold.. it looks shit haha. The Surface isn't smooth and the smooth glassy effect nonexistent. The Problem I assume is the geometry at the beginning. It's not smooth enough. And the only way I see to change this now is to somehow smoothen the selected Geometrey. Is it possible to apply for example subdivision Modifier to a specific area? Or what would be the best way to change that area to glass?

Answer (score 1):

Select all the helmet vertices and subdivide 3-4 times. Then go to object mode, select the whole mesh, and add a subdivision surface. Then maybe go to sculpt mode and smooth the helmet's glass a bit more if needed.